# Was Johann Heinrich Winkler really the first person who discovered field emission?

Tags: electricity, engineering

Who are the person or people who really discovered field emission in the first place? According to this slide https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261273784_Tutorial_Lecture_on_Field_Electron_Emission_Theory the field emission gas discharge was first reported by Johann Heinrich Winkler around 1744-45 and Joseph Priestley in his 1767 textbook. Another source said it was Robert Williams Wood who the first to observe field emission in 1897. The usual context of field emission is electron are emitted from a solid surface, such as metal, to vacuum. For example, the electrons that are generated attracted to the positive anode in vacuum. But didn't Robert Boyle already discovered that electric attraction can happen in vacuum? So, somehow we can say people already have the understanding that things such as field emission are possible as electric attraction can happen in vacuum?

In my opinion, whoever actually discovered field emission it could be anyone who spent their time experimenting with metals with an understanding of electrostatics somewhere around 1700 to 1800 or even earlier. Because many people with engineering background said the inventor of this and that is not really the first person to create or invent that something, as people always been copying each others' idea and then attempted to improve it by trial and error.

Comment: Nobody around 1700 to 1800 or earlier discovered field emission, they had no idea what electrons were or that they could be discharged. Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission#Early_history_of_field_electron_emission) is more careful with the phrasing:"*In retrospect, it seems likely that the electrical discharges reported by Winkler in 1744 were started by CFE from his wire electrode. However, meaningful investigations had to wait until after J.J. Thomson's identification of the electron in 1897*".